# how to add Headless js log geolocation for continuous interval

Tags: react-native

In Android Manifest I have added all the required permission for geolocation and added the service name as TimeTracking

```
package com.timetracking;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.react.HeadlessJsTaskService;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;
import com.facebook.react.jstasks.HeadlessJsTaskConfig;
import javax.annotation.Nullable;


public class TimeTracking extends HeadlessJsTaskService {

@Override
 protected @Nullable HeadlessJsTaskConfig getTaskConfig(Intent intent) {
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
WritableMap data = extras != null ? Arguments.fromBundle(extras) : null;
return new HeadlessJsTaskConfig(
    "TimeTracking", // Use the registered headless Task here
    data,
    500,
    true);
```

}
}

And in app.js page in react native I have called it.

```
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('TimeTracking', () =>   TimeTracking);
```

but nothing is displaying in console.Please can somebody tell the method to get timeInterval of location.

Thanks in advance.